# Google app engine - mail recipients limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I know that each recipient counts toward the Recipients Emailed (billable) quota and I can't send to more than is my daily quota.

But is there a limit how many recipients can a single email have?

For example can a single email created and sent through App engine Mail api have 8000 recipients?

Answer (score 1):

Is the daily limit [still 500](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=2208d7a55a9fa5a1&hl=en)? In that case, I would assume that a single email to 8000 people counts as 8000 emails, and thus would not be sent.

Comment: No. Free Default Quota are 2,000 recipients and 8 recipients/minute and 7,400,000 recipients maximum and 5,100 recipients/minute for Billing Enabled Default Quota. http://code.google.com/intl/sl-SI/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Mail

Comment: Google has changed the quota for email recently. The limit has gone down to 100 emails per day, with no option to buy more. Google advises to use SendGrid to send more email.

Comment: Quota is down to 10 at this time. While working on an API, I somehow suspect though that something is wrong as I hit the limit despite only using one and the same account for testing over and over again...

Comment: Update: I can confirm the "bug" above. On a new day, I sent 3 emails, to 2 different email accounts. I'm already down to 7 of 10 remaining emails for this 24 hour period.

Comment: As of 2018, the documentation is still not clear. It refers to a limit of 7000 Mail API calls but also a limit of 100 emails sent. The next paragraph then goes on to say 'If your app needs to send more than 7,000 messages per day, you can use a third-party mail provider, such as ....' So is it 7000 or 100? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Mail